# Use different gmail alias as the e-mail sender address

Tags: go, smtp, gmail

I have a function that sends an email.

I'm using go-simple-mail

```
    server := mail.NewSMTPClient()
    server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    server.Port = 587
    server.Username = "sample@gmail.com"
    server.Password = "password"
    server.Encryption = mail.EncryptionTLS

    smtpClient, err := server.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    email := mail.NewMSG()
    email.SetFrom("From me <alias@gmail.com>")
    email.AddTo(receiverEmail)
    email.SetSubject("Forgot Password")

    email.SetBody(mail.TextHTML, htmlBody)

    err = email.Send(smtpClient)
```

I want to use an alias email, but when I sent the email it still uses sample@gmail.com to the receiver, is there a way to use different email alias?

Comment: You have authenticated your sender to Gmail as `sample@gmail.com`; why the server should allow you to send the mail as someone else? Some SMTP servers do allow this but I don't know of any way to have distinct Gmail accounts be able to send mails using each other's identities.

Comment: GMail and certain other Google services allow you to add multiple email addresses (after proper authentication). What you try may work with previously added, authenticated emails, but it won't work with any random emails of course. You just can't send emails in anyone's name, that would completely defeat the authenticity of emails.